# React com.github.facebook.watchman.plist for write: Not a directory

Tags: ios, node.js, facebook, react-native

I have tried all the possible way after google but nothing is working I have updated Xcode 8.1 and Updated MAC OS with latest NodeJs

```
React packager ready.

2016-12-06T00:09:00,331: [cli] Failed to open /Users/anilyadav/Library/LaunchAgents/com.github.facebook.watchman.plist for write: Not a directory

2016-12-06T00:09:00,331: [cli] Failed to open /Users/anilyadav/Library/LaunchAgents/com.github.facebook.watchman.plist for write: Not a directory

Watchman:  watchman--no-pretty get-sockname returned with exit code null 2016-12-06T00:09:00,331: [cli] Failed to open /Users/anilyadav/Library/LaunchAgents/com.github.facebook.watchman.plist for write: Not a directory
```

Answer (score 0):

There's an error with your watchman, try this:

```
npm r -g watchman
brew update && brew upgrade
brew install watchman
```

Comment: I am stuck from last 3 days

Comment: I am using Mac OS Sierra. Is react-native not working on Sierra ?